# Как хранить служебную информацию в табе?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Я создаю в QTabWidget динамические табы, в котором есть динамически созданные QLabel-ы. У каждого QLabel есть свой номер. 
Мне надо хоронить этот номер в табе, чтоб по нажатию на кнопку он смотрел currentIndex() таба и этот номер QLabel-а.
Сейчас я храню эту информацию в TabToolTip и записываю её так :

```
decksTabWidget->setTabToolTip(deskCount,QString::number(imageLabel->getID()));
```

Но это костыль, где же лучше хранить данные о номере QLabel?

Comment: QObject::setProperty

Comment: @Alexander Chernin не совсем понял у QTabWidget нет setProperty

Comment: @IvanTriumphov у всех QObject есть. QTabWidget наследуется от QWidget, QWidget от QObject и от QPaintDevice.

Comment: @vegorov можно пример? Я пока не понимаю как это использовать

Comment: `tabWidget->currentWidget()->setProperty("descCount", QString::number(imageLabel->getID()));` типа такого наверное. Не уверен. Это выставление (добавление) свойства текущему виджету (табу)

Comment: @vegorov спасибо